# How do you make functions that wrap up Shiny reactive functions()?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a package that takes a lot of "boiler plate" Shiny input and output objects, and wraps them up in a function.  The idea is to sacrifice a bit of customisation for quick start apps.

For example:

### function sourced or in package

```
AuthMenuMacro <- function(input, session, code){

  …other observe functions that update menus….

  …other output functions that output plots, data tables….

  AuthToken <- reactive({

    token <- getTokenFromCode(code)

  })

}
```

### server.r

```
code <- createAuthenticationCode()

shinyServer(function(input, output, session)){

  AuthMenuMacro(input, output, code)

  output$API_plot <- renderPlot({

    ## error as can’t see function AuthToken() within AuthMenuMacro()
    data <- getAPIData(AuthToken())

    plot(data)

  }) 
}
```

The reactive function AuthToken() is within another function, and I can't reach its value from outside the enclosing function.  I get various errors reporting I can't work with reactive environemnts etc.

I tried using a list return, but this gave an error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

### attempt returning via a list

```
AuthMenuMacro <- function(input, session, code){

  …other observe functions that update menus….

  …other output functions that output plots, data tables….

  AuthToken <- reactive({

    token <- getTokenFromCode(code)

  })

  AuthTable <- reactive({

    table <- getTableFromCode(code)      

  })

  return(list(code=AuthToken(),
              table=AuthTable())

}
```

I have also tried using <<- and environments, as well as reactiveVariables() but it doesn't seem to work, but I may have the syntax wrong.

I can get close to what I want if in the above example I put AuthToken() and the other functions in say 'auth.r' and source it using:

### server.r

```
code <- createAuthenticationCode()

shinyServer(function(input, output, session)){

  source('auth.r', local=T)

  output$API_plot <- renderPlot({

    ## now works as AuthToken() in correct environment
    data <- getAPIData(AuthToken())

    plot(data)

  }) 
}
```

...but I would like a way to do it via functions to help simplify and pass variables easier, if possible.

**EDIT: Answer as below, but for clarification:**

I was returning the list with Shiny style objects rather than just treating it as a normal R function.

e.g. AccountCode() is wrong, AccountCode is right.

```
AuthMenuMacro <- function(input, session, code){

  …other observe functions that update menus….

  …other output functions that output plots, data tables….

AuthToken <- reactive({

    token <- getTokenFromCode(code)

})

AuthTable <- reactive({

  table <- getTableFromCode(code)      

})

return(list(code=AuthToken,  ## not AuthToken() as you would in server.r
          table=AuthTable))  ## not AuthTable() as you would in server.r

}
```

### server.r

```
auth <- AuthMenuMacro
token <- auth$code ## not auth$code()
table <- auth$table ## not auth$table()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN get the first server.r to work, but I think it's in really bad taste to call a function and have it add variables to the caller's environment. If there's only a single reactive expression you want to make available in the caller's environment, how about this:

```
AuthMenuMacro <- function(input, session, code){
  …other observe functions that update menus….
  …other output functions that output plots, data tables….
  reactive({
    token <- getTokenFromCode(code)
  })
}
```

server.r:

```
code <- createAuthenticationCode()

shinyServer(function(input, output, session)){
  AuthToken <- AuthMenuMacro(input, output, code)
  output$API_plot <- renderPlot({
    ## error as can’t see function AuthToken() within AuthMenuMacro()
    data <- getAPIData(AuthToken())
    plot(data)
  }) 
}
```

If you have multiple reactive expressions to return, then have AuthMenuMacro return a named list whose values are all reactive expressions. e.g.:

```
code <- createAuthenticationCode()

shinyServer(function(input, output, session)){
  auth <- AuthMenuMacro(input, output, code)
  output$API_plot <- renderPlot({
    ## error as can’t see function AuthToken() within AuthMenuMacro()
    data <- getAPIData(auth$AuthToken())
    plot(data)
  })
  observe({
    cat("Auth info:", auth$AuthInfo(), "\n")
  })
}
```

Comment: It is multiple reactive expressions I need, so are you saying the syntax for returning them is something like: return(list(auth=AuthToken(), table=AuthTable()) - I think thats what I tried first but got the error? Is it possible to see the syntax in an example?

Comment: I added an example returning a named list in the OP

Comment: ahh it worked when making the example!  I should have just treated it as a normal function - I was adding AuthToken() instead of AuthToken